# How should json serializing method do with attrs that should be links?

Tags: rest, serialization, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I am trying to implement DDD/clean architecture principles in a small REST service. I have got a task class:

```
@attr.s
class Task:
    id: str = attr.ib()
    url: str = attr.ib()

    images_paths: Optional[List[str]] = attr.ib(default=None)
    text_path: Optional[str] = attr.ib(default=None)
```

And I need two json serialization methods.
I need one to be able to store the json object in mongodb and then retrieve it in the same state. So I want the json look as follows:

```
{'id': '1', 'url': 'aaa.com', 'images_paths': ['img.png'], text_path: 'text.txt'}
```

And one more that will be json output form REST API

```
{'id': '1', 'url': 'aaa.com', 'images_paths': ['localhost/tasks/1/images/img.png'], text_path: 'localhost/tasks/1/text/text.txt'}
```

And according to DDD principles, I pressume both are json serialzation methods and should be in an infrastructure layer, am I right?
Are they correct from DDD point of view? How should they be called is both do json serialization?

And I am also not sure about tests. Popular test for serialization is to do:

```
assert task_from_json(task_to_json(task)) == task
```

But I cannot do such a test for the REST API json case

Answer (score 1):

From the clean architecture point of view, business layer you should not care about how to store your objects in database or how to reprsent it in web.

Your business layer should know that there is an interface, that responsible for storing and fetching objects

```
interface TaskStorage {
    fun save(Task)
    fun fetchTaskById(id: Integre): Task
}
```

and the interface for web representation

```
interface SomeView {
    fun render(Task)
}
```

And only data layer will know that Task should be converted to `json` representation and stored to Mongo.
And only view layer will know that Task will be represented as `json`.

Of course, you should have 2 Converters from Task to `json`:

- one on the Data access layer
- and one on the presentation layer.

And main idea is: Domain layer should not be aware about any Json representation